# Reading data from json_encode (php) in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, json

I am reading data from the MySQL database with using a querystring in my website url.

```
Example: www.test.com/user.php?username=mike
```

I read data from the database that belongs to the username (in this example: mike).

This is my PHP file which does that:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT LOWER(username) AS username FROM user WHERE username = '$username'");

$rows = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $rows[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
```

This PHP file returns:

```
[{"username":"mike"}]
```

The data that has been read is showing correctly like how a JSON file should be.

Afer this, I want to read the JSON value in Objective C (xcode).

I try to read that value from JSOn in Objective C as below:

```
- (void) loadJsonData
{

NSString *stringLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.test.com/user.php?username=%@", self.txtUsername.text];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: stringLink];

    [AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"application/x-javascript"]];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request     success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

        [self parseJSONData:JSON];


    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"Error :%@",response);
    }];

    [operation start];
}

-(void) parseJSONData:(id) JSON
{
    [self.loginArray removeAllObjects];

    if(JSON != NULL)
    {
        for (NSDictionary* dict in JSON) {

            User *user = [[User alloc] init];

            user.username = [dict objectForKey:@"username"];

            [self.loginArray addObject:user];
        }
    }
}
```

But this code doesn't read the value from the JSON.

But when I create a .JSON file (I call it "test.json") and I save this data into that file: `[{"username":"mike"}]` and I change the URL in the Objective C code to `www.test.com/test.json`, then my Objective C code reads the value....

So when I create a .JSON file, my Objective C code reads the data.
But when I want to read directly from the PHP file, my Objective C code doesn't read the data.

Can someone help me, or explain me why this code doesn't read from the PHP file? I'm encoding JSON too in the PHP file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once, and found out that my PHP was not returning UTF8 encoded JSON. Could this be your problem, too?

Comment: When I change the database attribute 'username' from latin to UTF8, then the PHP returns nothing...